# AXIOS get request failed 400 React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, get, request, axios

I am trying to make an axios get request to this endpoint, but I am keep getting this error " [Error: Request failed with status code 400]".

```
 clikk = () => {
    console.log('saasdasdl');
    var user = 'reflect-user';
    var pass = 'user1Pass';
    let dta = JSON.stringify({
      username: 'test.admin',
      password: 'password',
      emailAddress: 'test@gmai.com',
    });
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Basic ctesmtVmbGVjdC11c2VyOnVzZXIxUGFzcw==',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      accept: 'application/json',
    };

    // var bytes = utf8.encode(user + ':' + pass);
    // var authorizationBasic = base64.encode(bytes);
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://IpOfServer:8080/api/v1/user/getUser?all=true',
      headers: headers,
      data: qs.parse({
        username: 'test.admin',
        password: 'password',
        emailAddress: 'test@gmai.com',
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        //const nameList = res.data;
        //this.setState({nameList});
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

However same request is working in POSTMAN so API may not be involved ish? I've also tried to AXIOS example provided by POSTMAN but I am getting the same error.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"username":"test.admin","password":"password","emailAddress":"test6@gmai.com"});

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://IpOfServer:8080/api/v1/user/getUser?all=true',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Basic cmVmbGVjdC11c2VyOnVzZXIxUGFzcw==', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using localhost, you need to use your local IP address

Comment: I changed it just to give an example and to hide the  IP of the deployed server. I edited for clarification.

Comment: does the API allow calls in the browser from the other domain?  What are your CORS settings?

Comment: You are most likely getting a 400 on the request due to a CORS error, especially since it works in postman. Your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that needs to be set on the server side, not the client end like you have here. If you control the server, make sure the CORS stuff set up right there. If not, you may need to set up some sort of proxy to run your requests through

Comment: Enabled all the CORS for each endpoint but still getting that response. I will look now into the proxy thing.